# Binding a function without giving parameter types

Tags: c++, function, stl, bind, stdmap

I've got some difficult (for me) problem with functions in C++.
I've made some classes, like Numbers, Characters and so.
Each class has a `void add` function, but Numbers have `void add(int v)`, Characters - `void add(char c)`, etc.
In the main function, I've got Numbers and other classes' instances (numbs, charcts) and I would like to bind those with std::map, so I will be able to call functions like that:

```
func_map["numbers"]["add"](12);
```

which will be the same as:

```
numbs.add(12);
```

But it'll be easier for me, if I could call methods by giving just their names as strings (like show above).
How should I do that?

Comment: I think you might be happier using a different language, JavaScript or something. Not saying you can't get that to work in C++ but you're really fighting the language.

Comment: Are you sure that's easier?  Looks harder to call and read to me...

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey it's easier to call later. User can type "numbers add 2" and I don't have to parse user's input with much coding.

Comment: you really need dynamic type language for this. it is not possible for compiler to type-check that `func_map["numbers"]["add"]` is a function take `int` and `func_map["numbers"]["someotherfunction"]` is a function take something else

Comment: you need something like `boost::any`, and make all your member functions be functions that take `vector<any>` as argument and check they are valid at run time.

Comment: You need to implement a lookup table yourself because C++ does not support runtime metaprogramming. Template can do something similar but not calling by function name string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would warn you against such a design.

But, well, if you absolutely need that, you have to define a common interface to your functions. That is, your functions must have the same prototype.

For example, you can define some container class (or use something like boost::variant) that can be constructed from different data types, and you can write your 'add' functions so they accept an object of this class. What I mean is:

```
class DataContainer { 
 public:
  DataContainer(int n) { int_data_ = n; }
  DataContainer(char c) { int_data_ = c; }
  DataContainer(const string s) { string_data_ = s; }
 // let them be public to make code shorter
  int int_data_;
  string string_data_;
};

typedef void (*OpMethod)(const DataContainer);

void NumberAdd(const DataContainer data) {
  // work with data.int_data_
}

map<string, map<string, OpMethod> > funcmap; 

...
  funcmap["number"]["add"] = NumberAdd;
```

Binding class methods would be a bit more difficult (you should specify an object instance as well). Consider using std::function.